# Error con un modulo que saque un mensaje en la consola de odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo13

soy nuevo con odoo y quiero hacer un módulo que haga un log en la consola, nada más pero no soy capaz, tengo esto como código solamente:

```
print('todo okey ----------+++++++++++++-----------')
```

En mi **manifest**.py tengo esto que me he encontrado:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "pruebas",

    'summary': """
        Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
        subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

    'description': """
        Long description of module's purpose
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    # Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
    # Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_module_category_data.xml
    # for the full list
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base','product'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        #'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
}
```

Pero al instalarlo y demás no me salta ningún error y demás pero no logro que me salte ese mensaje, si entro a productos porque en el manifest pone lo de product sigo sin ver nada.
¿Alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo? Muchas gracias, estoy usando un odoo community v13 y python 3.8.6